# coordinate transformation in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

I'm confused about coordinate transformations. What I understand is, that if we have
$$
f(x(t))=g(x(t)),
$$
that we can write for each (bijective) $h(x)$
$$
f\circ h(x(t))=g\circ h(x(t)).
$$
If we can solve this, then we get an $x(t)$, such that $h^{-1}\circ x(t)$ is a solution in the old coordinates. In the case of  differential equation, I'm confused though. Say we have
$$
\dot x(t)=x(t).
$$
Now it seems that we can't speak of two functions that are equal (like $f$ and $g$ in our previous example), but it seems to me that we can still take a (diffeomorphism) $h(x)$, but I wouldn't know how that would work. You can't just composite each side with $h(x)$ like I did in the first example.

I hope my confusion is clear and that someone can help me out!